# Unable to export spans from OTEL to Elastic APM Server

Tags: elastic-stack, zipkin, apm, observability, otel

I have a nestjs application that i want to instrument. I am collecting traces using OTEL and exporting it to zipking and elastic apm server. My main focus is to trace all my graphql queries. I am able to view all my graphql queries on zipkin but not on kibana. All i can see on kibana is transaction with name 'POST /graphql/*' and none of the graphq attributes are present in that trannsaction.

my otel config is folloiwng:

```
receivers:
  otlp:
    protocols:
      grpc:
      http:

processors:
  batch:
    timeout: 10s
exporters:
  zipkin:
    endpoint: 'http://zipkin:9411/api/v2/spans'
  logging:
    loglevel: warn
  otlp/elastic:
    # Elastic APM server https endpoint without the "https://" prefix
    endpoint: 'http://apm-server:8200'
    tls:
      insecure: true
    headers:
      # Elastic APM Server secret token
      Authorization: 'Bearer '

service:
  pipelines:
    traces:
      receivers: [otlp]
      processors: [batch]
      exporters: [zipkin, logging, otlp/elastic]
    metrics:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging, otlp/elastic]
    logs:
      receivers: [otlp]
      exporters: [logging, otlp/elastic]
```

My apm-server.yml contains :

```
apm-server:
  host: '127.0.0.1:8200'
output.elasticsearch:
 hosts: ['localhost:9200']
```

I tried exporting traces to APM server but traces dont showup on kibana. I need to see all details of graphql call on kibana.